# .htaccess Issue with pages, images accessed like folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This area is not my strongest area. But feel I have a general understanding.

Ok, so my issue is this. I have a company I work for and for some reason these can be accessed:

http://www.pets4you.com/cats/ (Wrong, should not be able to and no folder called cats)
http://www.pets4you.com/cats.html (Correct URL)

Gets better:
pets4you.com/images/classifieds/ad_8e286189f9c4e622ea12ebdcdd10b646 (Huh?)
pets4you.com/images/classifieds/ad_8e286189f9c4e622ea12ebdcdd10b646.jpg

(Could not make URL's, 2 link limit here I guess)

My hosting company told me it was:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I told them they were wrong. That's a trace and commenting that out changes nothing.

Any ways, my code (Yes, alot of stuff, tell that to my boss!):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^(.*\.(css|js))$ min/index.php?f=$1&debug=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.pets4you.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN COMPRESSION AND CACHING
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Enable compression
    # AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript text/html text/plain text/xml image/x-icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies deliver correct content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
        # Ensure proxies deliver compressed content correctly
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # No ETags, No Pragma
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset ETag
    # Default cache time to 1 year (31536000 sec)
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>

# No ETags
FileETag none
# CACHE SETTINGS (mod_expires)

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Turn on Expires
    # set default to "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault A31536000
    ExpiresActive On
    # html - "modification plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/html M3600
    # css and JavaScript - "modification plus 6 weeks"
    ExpiresByType text/css M3628800
    ExpiresByType text/javascript M3628800
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript M3628800
</IfModule>

# No cache for php-files
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch> 
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    #php_value output_handler ob_gzhandler
    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_flag log_errors On
    php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
    php_value post_max_size 500M
    php_value memory_limit 1000M
    php_flag zlib.output_compression on
    php_value zlib.output_compression_level 2
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime Off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
    php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
    php_flag suhosin.session.encrypt Off
    php_value session.auto_start 0
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 54000
    php_value session.gc_divisor 500
    php_value session.gc_probability 1
    php_value mysql.connect_timeout 1000
    php_value mysql.allow_persistent Off
</IfModule>
##############
# ERROR PAGES#
##############
ErrorDocument 401 /errors.php?code=401
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php?code=500
ErrorDocument 403 /errors.php?code=403
ErrorDocument 400 /errors.php?code=400
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?code=404
######################
# BREED DESCRIPTIONS #
######################
RewriteRule ^dog_breed_description/teapoodle/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dog_breed_description/poodle/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dog_breed_description/toypoodle/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dog_breed_description/poodle/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^dog_breed_description/([^/]+) descriptions.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat_breed_description/([^/]+) descriptions.php?page=$1 [NC]
############
# CALENDAR #
############
#RewriteRule ^submitevent.html calendar.php?action=submitEvent [NC]
#RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) errors.php?code=404 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) errors.php?code=404 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]+)/([^/]+) calendar.php?year=$1&month=$2 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^calendar/([^/]+) calendar.php?year=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^calendar/ calendar.php [NC]
#################
# PET DIRECTORY #
#################
RewriteRule ^petsupplies/dogs/(.*).html/?$ directory.php?type=dog&page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^petsupplies/cats/(.*).html/?$ directory.php?type=cat&page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^petsupplies/(.*).html/?$ directory.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^petsupplies/search.php?$ directory.php?page=search [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^petsupplies/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/petsupplies.html [R=301,L]
###############
# PET GALLERY #
###############
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+) gallery.php?breed=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/?$ gallery.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/index.html?$ gallery.php [R=301,L]
############
# ARTICLES #
############
RewriteRule ^petarticles/([^/]+) articles.php?action=a&id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^petarticles/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/petarticles.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^petarticles?$ http://www.pets4you.com/petarticles.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^petarticles.html/?$ articles.php [L]
RewriteRule ^articles_search.php/?$ articles.php [QSA,L]
################
# LOST & FOUND #
################
RewriteRule ^lost_found.html/?$ lost_found.php [QSA,NC,L]
########
# DOGS #
########
RewriteRule ^studservice.html?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^puppiesforsale/([^/]+) http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dogs/([^/]+) http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dogs/ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^dogs.html?$ dogs.php?start=0 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^dogs1/?$ dogs.php?start=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^dogs2/?$ dogs.php?start=2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^cats/ http://www.pets4you.com/cats.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^cats.html/?$ cats.php [L]

RewriteRule ^puppiesforsale.html?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^teapoodle.html?$ http://www.pets4you.com/poodle.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^toypoodle.html?$ http://www.pets4you.com/poodle.html [R=301,L]
#############
# BREEDERS #
############
#RewriteRule ^dogbreeders/([^/]+) dog_breeders.php?breed=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^dogbreeders/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dog_breeders.html [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^dogbreeders.html/?$ dog_breeders.php [L]

#RewriteRule ^catbreeders/([^/]+) cat_breeders.php?breed=$1 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^catbreeders/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/cat_breeders.html [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^catbreeders.html/?$ cat_breeders.php [L]
################
# STATE PET ADS #
################
RewriteRule ^localpetads/(.*).html?start=([0-9])/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^localpetads/(.*).html/?$ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^localpetads.html?$ http://www.pets4you.com/localpetads/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^localpetads/([^/]+)/([^/]+) http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^localpetads/([^/]+) http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^localpetads/ http://www.pets4you.com/dogs.html [R=301,L]
###########
# GENERAL #
###########
RewriteRule ^sitemap.html?$ sitemap.php?start=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap2/?$ sitemap.php?start=2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap3/?$ sitemap.php?start=3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap4/?$ sitemap.php?start=4 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^terms.html/?$ terms.html [L]
RewriteRule ^google97ce2a2538777af1.html/?$ google97ce2a2538777af1.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^googlef7b2dff2a5d7b41b.html/?$ googlef7b2dff2a5d7b41b.htm [L]
RewriteRule ^dogvideos/ videos.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^topdogs/ breedratings.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html/?$ pets4you.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also, sometimes when I type in "www.pets4you.com" it directs to https (?)
Something else that has me clueless.

Not my strongest area, .htaccess. Anything wrong let me know. All the redirects work fine. Just boggles my mind what the other things are caused by.

Thanks!

Comment: And to point out, even though there is always some difference. When I run this same file on my local machine, none of the above happens. Only when live on our hosted server.

Comment: Did you inherit that mess or were you learning by doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, what a mess, Shawn. Without proper knowledge of your server's internals (the main config files (httpd-xxx.conf) that is) there's no way of telling exactely what's going on.

What I found was:

1. The cat URL issue. The responsible directives are:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^cats/ http://www.pets4you.com/cats.html [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^cats.html/?$ cats.php [L]
   ```
2. As for the images being served with and without proper file-extensions: This sounds like `mod_spelling` is loaded into Apache (you would have to check with your hoster).

Comment: Also forgot I still had the cat and dog conditions in the .htaccess too. But I also know they will not trigger until I actually make a cats and dogs folder. Seeing I have the code in the htaccess but no folders created, why it does not redirect. But the moment i do make a folder, they work. Any ways... I now have something to work from at least. Again, thanks

Comment: As a general rule: Please upvote and/or accept answers that were helpful to you. Oh, and btw. you're welcome.

Comment: Done, a bit late. Forgot i had this out here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the only way I could actually resolve this was doing this.

Instead of using cats.php, I renamed the file to catspage.php. For some reason using the same name as the request caused weird things to happen. cats.html directs to cats.php, but cats/ was able to be pulled up and calling cats.php. Remembering now, I had to deal with this before with another client.

After renaming the files, those URLs stopped working, what I wanted. However the image thing is our server. Every single one of our sites we have with them does this.

Thanks again all.